# Vue 3 Vite load fonts from assets with Font Loading API results in 404

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, fonts, vite

I am trying to dynamically load fonts from the assets directory in Vue 3 (Typescript) using Vite. But the whole thing results in a 404 error.

[image]

```js
const fonts = import.meta.glob('@/assets/fonts/*.otf')

console.log(fonts)

async function loadFonts() {
  for (const path in fonts) {
    const fontName = path.split('/')[3].split('-')[0]

    console.log(fontName)

    const myFont = new FontFace(fontName, `url('${path}')`)
    await myFont.load()
    document.fonts.add(myFont)

    console.log(myFont)
  }
}

loadFonts()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your codes in my configuration, and it works fine.

So, I think you may have wrong path alias of `@` in your **vite.config.ts** file.

You can see the error says that the source path is `http://localhost:3000/assets/fonts/Acumin-Bold.otf`, but the real fonts path is `src/assets/fonts/Acumin-Bold.otf`. Your **src** is missing.

Below is my **vite.config.ts**, you can take a look.

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
  }
}
```